# Security jar missing in HDP2.0 for hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

We have upgraded our cluster from HDP 1.3 to HDP 2.0.
Because of this migration, we are facing certain issue with the code which used to work earlier.

1. Bulk load for Hbase using `Importtsv` comand: Security jar which was there in HDP 1.3 is missing in HDP 2.0. So, we are not able to map the jars properly.
2. Pig command filter which worked in 1.3 cluster is not working in 2.0.

How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop provides a good backward compatibility. Make sure that every node in your cluster is upgraded (all Hadoop services) from 1.3 to 2.0, including Pig, Hive, HBase, Sqoop....